# What is a mapping cocone for a map of cochain complexes $f: A \to B$?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I suspect that the [mapping cocone](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mapping+cocone) of a map of cochain complexes should be related to the mapping cone by the suspension or translation:  $$\mathrm{Cocone}(f) = \mathrm{Cone}(f)[-1].$$

That is, in degree $q$, we should have $\mathrm{Cocone}(f)^q = \mathrm{Cone}(f)^{q-1}$.

I've picked up most of my homological algebra from Kashiwara & Schapira, but they don't discuss the mapping cocone (only the mapping cone), and neither do any of the other sources I've looked through.

Comment: I would say that $\operatorname{Cocone}f=\operatorname{Cone}(f)[-1]$. The point of the mapping cocone is to have a distinguished triangle $$\operatorname{Cocone}f\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow\operatorname{Cocone}f[1]$$.

Comment: Oops, yeah you're right. Got my shift mixed up